# Python Tkinter problem with looping to check if mouse clicked on line(canvas)

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I want to check if the mouse clicked on a line on Tkinter canvas or not, if on a line then which line.
I had made this to detect mouse clicks.

```
class Link:
    def __init__(self,Node1,Node2,canvas,width=5):
        if self not in canvas.LinkList:
            self.start_coor = Node1.Centre
            self.final_coor = Node2.Centre
            self.Canvas = canvas
            self.Width = width
            self.Shape = canvas.create_line(self.start_coor,self.final_coor,width=width)
            Node1.connected(Node2)
            self.Canvas.LinkList.append(self)
            self.Nodes = [Node1,Node2]

            self.Clicked = False

            dy = self.final_coor[1] - self.start_coor[1]
            dx = self.final_coor[0] - self.start_coor[0]
            self.m = dy/dx
            self.c = self.start_coor[1] - self.m*self.start_coor[0]

    def onLineCheck(self,x,y,field=False):
        #y = mx + c
        #y - mx - c = 0
        if not field:
            field = self.Width
        if (x < self.start_coor[0] and x < self.final_coor[1]) or (x > self.start_coor[0] and x > self.final_coor[1]) or (y < self.start_coor[1] and y < self.final_coor[1]) or (y > self.start_coor[1] and y > self.final_coor[1]):
            return False
        temp =  y - (self.m*x) - self.c
        if abs(temp) <= field:
            return True
        return False
class InputCanvas(Canvas):

    def __init__(self,master=None, **kw):
        super().__init__(master,**kw)
        self.NodeList = []
        self.LinkList = []
        self.Mode = "Nodes"
    def anyLinkClicked(self,e):
        x,y = getMousePosition(e)
        for l in self.LinkList:
            if l.onLineCheck(x,y):
                return l
        return False
```

Every time when a link is created, it will automatically append itself to the canvas.LinkList. I am sure this part of the code is working properly.
So far the program works well with 1 line on Canvas(even if I remove it and draw a new one it is still working) but cannot handle more than 1 line, it can only respond to the first line created. Even if I remove the first line, the second created line won't work.
I've tried printing out the result of each onLineCheck(), it seems like the loop is looping properly through each line but it is not catching mouse clicks.
Any idea to help?

Comment: Your code should cater the case when `dx` is 0 which will raise divided by zero exception.

Comment: Read up on [Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) and [Canvas.find_*-method's](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_closest-method)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on the following line:

```
if (x < self.start_coor[0] and x < self.final_coor[1]) or (x > self.start_coor[0] and x > self.final_coor[1]) or (y < self.start_coor[1] and y < self.final_coor[1]) or (y > self.start_coor[1] and y > self.final_coor[1]):
    return False
```

- `x < self.final_coor[1]` should be `x < self.final_coor[0]`
- `x > self.final_coor[1]` should be `x > self.final_coor[0]`

Also you should also cater *vertical line*, i.e. `dx` is zero as your code will raise `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero`.

You can use `Canvas.find_overlapping()` function to find which `Link` is clicked:

```
def anyLinkClicked(self, e):
    x, y = getMousePosition(e)
    found = self.find_overlapping(x, y, x, y)
    if found:
        for l in self.LinkList:
            if found[0] == l.Shape:
                return l
    return False
```

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was looking for.